# Projecting self referencing multi level Entities In Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Projecting self referencing multi level entities in Entity Framework 6.

Let's say that I have a `Category` entity as follows:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }        

    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public Category()
    {            
        SubCategories = new HashSet<Category>();
        Products = new HashSet<Product>();
    }
}
```

And I would like to map the whole `Category` `DbSet` with all the hierarchy to a following POCO class (while including all possible levels of sub and parent categories):

```
public class CategoryView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }        

    public CategoryView ParentCategory { get; set; }

    public List<CategoryView> SubCategories { get; set; }

    public int ProductCount { get; set; }

    public Category()
    {            
        SubCategories = new HashSet<CategoryView>();            
    }
}
```

Please bear in mind that a single category may have unlimited levels of subcategories as follows:

```
Category (Level 0)
    SubCategory1 (Level 1)
    SubCategory2
        SubCategory2SubCategory1 (Level 2)
        SubCategory2SubCategory2
            SubCategory2SubCategory2SubCategory1 (Level 3)
            ... (Level N)
    SubCategory3
```

When tried to create hierarchy with recursive a method which tries to process every single categories sub and parent categories, got `stackoverflow exception`, since it get stuck between the first category (`Category`) and the first subcategory (`SubCategory1`) due to relation between `ParentCategory` and `SubCategories`.

What is the best and elegant way of doing such projection (without eliminating parents)? (Or is there any?)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: By projecting do you mean to produce `IQueryable<CategoryView>` or `IEnumerable<CategoryView>` would work? Also shouldn't `ParentCategory` and `SubCategories` of the `CategoryView` refer to `CategoryView` objects (and not `Category` as in the post)?

Comment: IvanStoev, jorgonor yes you are both right, copy/paste mistake POCO class is/should hold CategoryView instead of Category. IvanStoev, would like to have IEnumerable<CategoryView> we need to have at the end of projection result. Thanks.
on a side note jorgonor, the dictionary approach also causes stackoverflow error when tried to process sub-categories parent ones.

Comment: As I said, it must be the same dictionary for every function call. I guess you are calling a recursive function to create the sequence, every function call must share this instance. This prevents creating new instances with same ID. Unless you have a very big dataset, you shouldn't see any StackOverflowException.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't say if it's the best or elegant way, but it's pretty standard and efficient non recursive way of building such structure.

Start with loading all categories *without parent / child object links* using a simple projection:

```
var allCategories = db.Categories
    .Select(c => new CategoryView
    {
        Id = c.CategoryId,
        ParentCategoryId = c.ParentCategoryId,
        Name = c.Name,
        Description = c.Description,
        ProductCount = c.Products.Count()
    })
    .ToList();
```

then create a fast lookup data structure for finding `CategoryView` by `Id`:

```
var categoryById = allCategories.ToDictionary(c => c.Id);
```

then link the subcategories to their parents using the previously prepared data structures:

```
foreach (var category in allCategories.Where(c => c.ParentCategoryId != null))
{
    category.ParentCategory = categoryById[category.ParentCategoryId.Value];
    category.ParentCategory.SubCategories.Add(category);
}
```

At this point, the tree links are ready. Depending of your needs. either return the `allCategories` or the root categories if you need a real tree representation:

```
return allCategories.Where(c => c.ParentCategoryId == null);
```

P.S. Actually the `allCategories` list can be avoided, since `categoryById.Values` could serve the same purpose.

Comment: Thank you @Ivan this woks like charm!

Answer (score 2):

It might not be elegant, but a suitable solution is to have in your code a shared `IDictionary<int, CategoryView>`. When you are going to map an entity `Category` into a `CategoryView` check first if you have already created this object and set the reference stored in the dictionary instead of creating a `CategoryView` instance. When creating a new instance, store it in the dictionary. This is a way to take advantage of the primary key of your entity to avoid the infinite recursion issue in your code.

Also, notice that in your `CategoryView` object you shouldn't be referencing `Category` instances. Update it to reference `CategoryView` instances like this.

```
public class CategoryView
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }        

    // other properties ...

    public CategoryView ParentCategory { get; set; }

    public List<CategoryView> SubCategories { get; set; }

    public int ProductCount { get; set; }

    public CategoryView()
    {            
        SubCategories = new List<CategoryView>();
    }
}
```